# jira-python...get_server_info=True...invalid syntax

Tags: python, jira

Out of the blue, I'm faced with the following error when I deploy my code to kubernetes running python 3.6.6 and jira==1.0.15:

```
from jira import JIRA
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from jira.client import Comment  # noqa: E402
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 337
validate=False, get_server_info=True, async=False, logging=True, max_retries=3, proxies=None,
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It works just fine, however, in my local environment running mac/docker python 3.6.5 and jira==1.0.15.

I've seen the issue being discussed here: https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/603. But the difference in my situation is that I'm not using python 3.7 and the up arrow ^ in my error is not pointing to `async=False` but it's pointing to `get_server_info=True` instead.

I've been pulling my hair out over this one for the past several hours.  Can any shed any light on a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `SyntaxError` arrow isn't always exact (usually near the actual cause of the error), and as you can see from the directory name `usr/local/lib/python3.7/`, you are running Python 3.7. `async` and `await` are reserved keywords as of this version, so when the name `async` or `await` is used in purposes designed otherwise, a `SyntaxError` will be raised.

From a look of the link you linked, in the past week, the developers are working hard to fix this issue. It might not be complete fixed yet, but you can install the developmental version of your package by following the steps under "Development" https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/master/README.rst#Development.

Or, for coarse, you can install any version of Python < 3.7.

Comment: thanks so much for the response.  I'm such a goof for overlooking the python version.  When it was working, I had logged into my container and done a `python -V` and it came up with 3.6.6.  Anyway, I tried your suggestion of installing jira from git but ran into the following error while building...`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jira==2.0.0.dev20`. Is there any other way to get around this?  Can I install an older version? Or, can I peg my python version to 3.6.x?  Just exploring my options in case the jira fix doesn't come out for a while.

Comment: I'm not very clear on how they do stuff on git, so you might have to follow their recommended steps that I linked. And yes, the easiest and most stable way is to use a Python version less than 3.7 and also supported by your package. I'm quite sure using 3.6.x will work flawlessly.